# PHP gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", time()) returning wrong time

Tags: php, mysql

I have an Android App developed with Kodular that sends GPS coordinates from a smartphone to a PHP script that stores this data to a MySQL table.
The date is the server date.
Several smartphones participate on this group but in two of them the time is always wrong.
The date is stored as gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", time())
On those two smartphones where the date comes out wrong in the MySQL table, first, as the format implies, it should come as 24H format but it comes as 12H, the time is 1 hour behind what is the correct time.

As an example please check the MySQL table in question below:
[image: Removed non relevant information, please check timestamp for the problem]

The record at the top shows the correct GMT time as both units were active reporting GPS during the test.
The record at the bottom shows the time in 12h format and wrong time as 1h less than the correct one.

I tried several formatting suggestions found at the internet including setting date_default_timezone_set('GMT'); on top of the script but no change. The test was done at the same time on the two units shown on the table, same country, same time zone, only GPS coordinates different.

The problem could not come from the smartphone because it sets no date, date is generated by the same server as the one that works properly.

PHP code below:

```
<?php
include('iotaccess.php');
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

$devid = $latitude = $longitude = $altitude = $speed = $direction = $opstatus = $gpsstatus = $batstatus = "0";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $api_key_value = test_input($_POST["api_key"]);
    if($api_key == $api_key_value) {
        $devid       = test_input($_POST["devid"]);
        $latitude    = test_input($_POST["latitude"]);
        $longitude   = test_input($_POST["longitude"]);
        $altitude    = test_input($_POST["altitude"]);
        $speed       = test_input($_POST["speed"]);
        $direction   = test_input($_POST["direction"]);
        $opstatus    = test_input($_POST["opstatus"]);
        $gpsstatus   = test_input($_POST["gpsstatus"]);
        $batstatus   = test_input($_POST["batstatus"]);

        //if(test_input($_POST["gpsstatus"])==1){$gpsstatus=TRUE;}
        //if(test_input($_POST["batstatus"])==1){$batstatus=TRUE;}

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $DBuser, $DBpass, $DBname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        //$sql = "SELECT devid FROM GroupMembership WHERE devid='". $devid ."';";
        $sql = "SELECT gm.devid,gt.command FROM GroupMembership as gm JOIN GroupTracker as gt on gm.devid=gt.devid WHERE gm.devid='". $devid ."';";
        
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if($row['devid']=='') {
           echo "Devid not found.";
        } else {

          echo "command:".$row['command'];

          if($gpsstatus==1){
             $sql = "UPDATE GroupMembership set latitude=" .$latitude. ",longitude=" .$longitude. ",timestamp='" .gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", time()). "'";
             $sql = $sql. " WHERE devid='" .$devid. "';"; 
             if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                $sql = "UPDATE GroupTracker set altitude=" .$altitude. ",speed=" .$speed;
                $sql = $sql. ",direction=" .$direction. ",timestamp='" .gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", time()). "'"; 
                $sql = $sql. ",opstatus='" .$opstatus. "',gpsstatus=" .$gpsstatus. ",batstatus=" .$batstatus;
                $sql = $sql. " WHERE devid='" .$devid. "';";   
                $conn->query($sql);  
             } else {
               echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
             } 
          }else{
             $sql = "UPDATE GroupMembership set timestamp='" .gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", time()). "'";
             $sql = $sql. " WHERE devid='" .$devid. "';";
             if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                $sql = "UPDATE GroupTracker set timestamp='" .gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s", time()). "'"; 
                $sql = $sql. ",opstatus='" .$opstatus. "',gpsstatus=" .$gpsstatus. ",batstatus=" .$batstatus;
                $sql = $sql. " WHERE devid='" .$devid. "';";   
                $conn->query($sql);  
             } else {
               echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
             }              
          } 
       }
       $conn->close();

    } else {
      echo "Wrong API Key";
    }

} else {
  echo "No data posted with HTTP POST.";
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to show us the PHP code that creates and then saves the datetime to the database

Comment: To remove the possibility of error, you could always change the query to use `NOW()` rather than try and generate the date in PHP. **I assume the column is a real DATETIME datatype, and not a VARCHAR()??**

Comment: Hi, just checked, the column is timestamp.

Comment: Added code to the original post.

Comment: Riggs, I am probably messing up here. The column type is timestamp and not DATETIME, also I have made default to be CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Maybe I dont even have to save this column. How do I make sure it is going to be GMT and also 24Hs? Thanks

Comment: Not sure how that works at all. MySQL requires dates to be sent in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss` and not using `/`

Comment: Just changed column from timestamp to DATETIME, no change. Remover default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, no change. Found the format used on the PHP script as examples at the internet. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gmdate.php

Comment: TIMESTAMP is fine

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: SQL Injection, yes I have been told that, it is in development and will sure have to look into it when the bugs are sorted out. Thanks. I have already tried timestamp=NOW(), no change.

Comment: Your database and PHP are probably not using corresponding timezones. GMT is not ONE definite timezone btw, it matters whether it's +0, +1 etc. So your PHP is probably GMT+0 and your database is probably GMT+1, hence the hour difference. That doesn't explain the 12hr vs 24hr clock though, you'd probably have to look into some table structure, options/settings and/or data formats for that one.

Comment: Martin, I did solve the problem of the 12x42hs. I found the php used by the smartphones was not the same as the one as I posted above. Now the database is setting its own time. Now the time difference still remains and I am looking into your post above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this can ever have worked.

Dates should be passed to MySQL in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` so when you pass a date formatted with slashes, mysql should reject the query and given you an error

Change the date you calculate to either use

```
timestamp='" .gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()). "'";
```

Or simply use `NOW()` and let MySQL do all the work for you

```
timestamp=NOW()";
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was not in the script I sent that was why changes did not solve the problem. Your suggestion above sorted it out. Thanks Paulo